# File search from a folder using indexOf()

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

class FindFile {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      File dir = new File("D:/Abhishek/src/com/siemens/med/hs/sf/payer/billing/claiminterface");
      FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
         public boolean accept
         (File dir, String name) {
            return name.indexOf("Claim");
             }
      };
      String[] children = dir.list(filter);
      if (children == null) {
         System.out.println("Either dir does not exist or is not a directory");
      } 
      else {
         for (int i=0; i< children.length; i++) {
            String filename = children[i];
            System.out.println(filename);
         }
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: bananas are yellow. (This is a valid answer for your non-existing question).

Comment: Ask your question and try to make your questions self explainatory for future posts :)

Comment: oops!! forgot to ask the question.
I got this program from my friend. to search a file from a directory that has the name "Claims". 
Can anyone figure out the error.
{P.S- without using startsWith and endsWith }

Comment: @user2493183 You still didn't ask the question :)

Comment: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean"
Getting this error. Can anyone tell me what to do now?

Comment: Dont ask the question in the comments, edit your real question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something more like

```
return name.toLowerCase().indexOf("claim") > -1;
```

In your `FileFilter` class...

Comment: Indeed. His indentation made it harder to notice this boolean method :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thnx it worked.

Comment: @MarounMaroun The lack of an actual question made it hard :P